# Evaluate/change displaying value in Gridview using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, data-binding, gridview, binding

With javascript, in asp.net grid view am switching the displaying boolen value to string as follow

```
<asp:Label ID="Correct" Text='<%# Eval("Correct").ToString().Equals("true") ? " Correct " : " Wrong " %>'  runat="server"/></td>
```

is there any way to switch 3 different values if datatype is int & values are 1,2 & 3 to show respectively low, medium & high. I have tried as follows but its not working

```
<asp:Label ID="Difficulty" Text='<%# Eval("Difficulty").ToString().Equals("1") ? " low" : (("Difficulty").ToString().Equals("2") ? " medium " : " high ") %>'  runat="server"/></td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if this can be done with ternary operator - it is extremely hard to read. I'd say your best bet would be defining a function in corresponding code behind class:

```
protected string GetDifficultyText(object difficultyObj)
{
    string difficultyId = difficultyObj as string;

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(difficultyId))
    {
        return string.Empty; //or throw exception
    }

    switch (difficultyId)
    {
        case "1":
            return " low";
        case "2":
            return " medium";
        case "3":
            return " high";
        default:
            return string.Empty; //or throw exception
    }
}
```

And then calling it in the markup:

```
<asp:Label ID="Difficulty"
           Text='<%# GetDifficultyText(Eval("Difficulty")) %>'
           runat="server"/>
```

Comment: string difficultyId = difficultyObj as string;

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(difficultyId))
    {
        return string.Empty; //or throw exception
    }

should be
        string difficultyId = difficultyObj.ToString();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(difficultyId))
        {
            return string.Empty; //or throw exception
        }

Comment: @RohitChaudhari, depends on the version of framework you are using. Method `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` was introduced in C# 4.0 if I am not mistaken.